# WebService arroja WS00041: Service invocation threw an exception with message: nuel;

Tags: webservice

Soy nuevo en WebService e intento hacer una suma de dos números pero me da error al realizar el test:

> WS00041: Service invocation threw an exception with message : null;Refer to the server log for more details.
> Exceptions details : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionat org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:318)at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:82)at org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:133)at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)at org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:293)... 32 more Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class WS.calculadora Please see the server log to find more detail regarding exact cause of the failure.at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:163)at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:98)at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:223)at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:176)at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:263)at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:62)at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:131)at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy320.sumar(Unknown Source)... 37 more

Este es el código que usé:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;


@WebService(serviceName = "calculadora")
public class calculadora {

/**
 * Web service operation
 * @param num1
 * @param num2
 * @return 
 */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "sumar")
    public int sumar(@WebParam(name = "num1") int num1, @WebParam(name = "num2") int num2) {
        //TODO write your implementation code here:
        int suma = (num1 + num2);
        return suma;
    }
}
```

¿Dónde esta el error?
Gracias.

Comment: Y cómo lo estás invocando? Con qué datos?

Answer (score 0):

Pues el error está en el servidor

`Client received SOAP Fault from server: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Error creating managed object for class: class WS.calculadora`

y te está devolviendo una respuesta con el body vacío (por eso dice que `Service invocation threw an exception with message : null`).

Si tú mantienes el web service, debes revisar cómo está implementado el servicio para que, al recibir peticiones, las procese correctamente.

Comment: Agradezco tu interés..   pero como lo resuelvo..  sería de gran ayuda....   gracias.